# How to make sure that cells don't resize due to content?

Tags: html, css

When `table-layout: fixed` is set, all cells become of equal size until some content is added to them. Is there a way to keep their size equal even when the content is there? The content can either have width / height as a percentage of the cell or it can have fixed width. The table is responsive (if the content overflows, then it should be hidden).

How it looks now ( [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jokk9bd8/) ):

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 40vw;
  height: 40vw;
}
td {
  border: 3px solid grey;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 40px;
}
.aligner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.content {
  height: 60px;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <div class="aligner">
      </div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <div class="aligner">

      </div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <div class="aligner">
        <div class="content">
          hello world
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It would be fine if it could be solved just with flexbox (i.e. no table), but I'm not aware of how make it have always fixed amount of rows and columns of equal size so that it looks like the table in the images.

Small:

[image: small]

Medium:

[image: medium]

Large:

[image: large]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With CSS only, you can set the `width` and `height` on the `td` directly, and with `position:relative` + `overflow:hidden`, then set the inner div to `position:absolute`.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/68vytuuo/)**

```css
td {
  border: 3px solid grey;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.aligner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: 60px;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><div class="aligner">hello world</div></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or use a pseudo element + padding tricks for making the square table cells.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h1Lut7vo/)**

```css
table {
  width: 40vw;
}
td {
  border: 3px solid grey;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
td:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
.aligner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: 60px;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><div class="aligner">hello world</div></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```